# do html5 audio tags eat up resources

Tags: html, audio

I have pages where i need to play dozens of small audio file when the user clicks on things. Responsiveness is very important.

I'm thinking of using one  for each file, and preloading the audio files.  Is this the a reasonible approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's reasonable, and probably the correct solution. I recently wrote a demo application (http://www.soundscribe.com) that makes heavy use of individual (and simultaneous) audio clips in HTML5. IE9 and FF3/4 handle it well. Chrome has some issues that seem to be specifically related to simultaneous playback (which probably won't apply to your app). The biggest block I hit was in IE9, which seems to have a mysterious limit on the number of audio objects that can exist at once. The max is about 40, after which IE9 will silently fail to download the file. FF and Chrome both try to support an unlimited number.

The alternative approach of putting all the audio in a single file and changing the offset to play is a bad choice for several reasons. It's much more complicated to code, you need to keep up with additional metadata (where does the clip start, how long is it), and it's likely to work slightly different between browsers. And the worst part, there's really no way to know when your clip is fully loaded. You can only tell when the clip "can play through", which is determined by the browser based on the size of the audio file and the current download rate. This means that even after the browser reports the audio clip is ready, you may not be able to play a clip somewhere near the end.

Comment: The maximum I hit in ie9 is 41 simultaneous audios. 42nd and beyond don't load. Did you find any solution for this, by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

What I experience using SoundManager2 (audio Javascript lib) is that Chrome nor Firefox have no issues loading and playing multiple (100+) sounds through their Html5 capabilities
(Firefox must play OGG though)

With IE9 it's a different story. Looks like it has a limit to load and play no more than 40 sounds. :-(

As, the game we develop requires constantly to have 50+ sounds played within 1 minute period, we have to fallback to Flash for playing sounds on IE9.. luckily SM2 does it too

I also confirm this behaviour with html5 mode using jPlayer. I'm only able to create 40 instances of jPlayer. Each can preload and play sound that it defines.
41st and following instances will fail with an error on IE9/Windows7

Error: "Media URL could not be loaded"

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a reasonable approach. However you need to consider a couple of things.

- Each sound clip will need to be held in memory. While this is will not matter for most cases, users with a lot of tabs open, multiple programs open or old computers may get slow down on their computer. Especially if the sound files are large.
- From a usability point of view, if I hear a sound every time a click a button on the site, I'll leave immediately

Comment: I understand that the audio files themselves use memory - that's unavoidable, what I want to know is do i waste a lot of memory keeping instantiation dozens of audio tags as opposed to using just one and finding some other way to pre-load the .mp3 files.   - As to usability, this is a foreign-language learning program, the user is happy to hear sounds when he clicks things!