# IE9 multiple <audio> tags block further HTTP requests

Tags: html, audio, internet-explorer-9

I have a webpage with multiple  tags, such as:

```
<audio controls="controls" preload="metadata">
    <source type="audio/mpeg" src="file1.mp3"></source>
</audio>
```

Each  tag plays a different file, and each mp3 file is fairly long (i.e. they take up to a minute to be fully downloaded).

If I have more than 4  tags, only the first 4 will be displayed in IE9. The other ones will be displayed one by one, each time one of the first 4 audio players has finished loading its audio file.

In fact, clicking on any hyperlink in the page doesn't load the appropriate HTTP resource until one of the audio players stops loading. It seems as though the audio tags set a hard limit on the number of simultaneous HTTP connections. IE9 usually has a much higher limit, so this seems strange.

Other things to note:

- the audio files load and play fine by themselves

  - I don't need to files to be played simultaneously, I just want to have a page that shows multiple audio players for different files
  - I tried using different values (none | metadata | auto) for the preload attribute. 'none' hides the audio players completely in IE9,
    and metadata and auto show the same problem.
  - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6050771/532562) mentions that up to 40 players in IE9 should be okay, but I can't get beyond 4?

Any thoughts are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there are some glitches with IE9 when the **preload** attribute of audio tag is set to "**metadata**".

Possible workaround for more responsive behavior will be:

1. Setting `preload = "none"`
2. Wrapping `<audio>` tag with an image or div with a background image
3. Attach "click" event to the image/div which will trigger: `document.getElementById('audio1').play()`

Hope it suits your needs.